# FormDialog RESET - how to reinitialize data available in context?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have the following sample class below, where it initiates the value of FirstName and emailAddress from context.UserData.

This works well when I call the form, so I am not asked for FirstName or emailAddress since I always set it when testing.

However, if I input RESET, which FormDialog automatically handles, my debugger does not enter StartAsync() where I have a breakpoint. Then I am asked for my FirstName even though it is already available.

Here is a snippet of my conversation:
[image]

Am I initializing my data properly in StartAsync()? How do I make it stick even when RESET is called?

One curious thing I realized is if I comment out `.Field(nameof(AdultOptionCount)` and  `.Field(nameof(ChildOptionCount)` then RESET does not ask me for my Firstname.

Here is the full code that I use that always asks for FirstName AFTER reset.

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyDialogs
{
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public RootDialog()
    {
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        //This is a test so I am filling up CustomerAccount data here
        CustomerAccount ca = new CustomerAccount();
        ca.FirstName = "Oyen";
        ca.Email = "oyen@email.com";
        context.UserData.SetValue<CustomerAccount>("CustomerAccount", ca);

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        //this message is always ignored
        var message = await result;

        await context.PostAsync("Hello there! Let's get started.");

        //a bunch of questions are usually asked here to determine which LUIS Dialog I will call because I have several
        //right now, let's just go straight to the Application dialog

        var app = new MyApplication();
        context.Call(app, ApplicationResumeAfter);
    }

    private async Task ApplicationResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var message = await result;

        //do nothing else in this test
        context.Done(true);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class CustomerAccount
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
public class MyApplication : IDialog<string>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Call(new ApplyForm(), CompleteApplication);
    }

    private async Task CompleteApplication(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var message = await result;

        context.Done("SUCCESSFUL");
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ApplyForm : IDialog<ApplyForm>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        var state = new ApplyForm();

        CustomerAccount CustomerAccount;
        if (context.UserData.TryGetValue<CustomerAccount>("CustomerAccount", out CustomerAccount))
        {
            state.FirstName = CustomerAccount.FirstName;
            state.EmailAddress = CustomerAccount.Email;
        }

        var form = new FormDialog<ApplyForm>(
            state,
            BuildForm,
           FormOptions.PromptInStart);

        context.Call(form, this.AfterBuildForm);
    }

    [Prompt("What is your **{&}**?")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Prompt("What is your **{&}**?")]
    public string EmailAddress;

    [Numeric(0, 15)]
    [Prompt("How many adults will attend?")]
    public int AdultOptionCount { get; set; }

    [Numeric(0, 15)]
    [Prompt("How many children will attend?")]
    public int ChildOptionCount { get; set; }

    public static IForm<ApplyForm> BuildForm()
    {
        var form = new FormBuilder<ApplyForm>()
                .Field(nameof(FirstName),
                active: (state) =>
                {
                    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.FirstName);
                })
                .Field(nameof(EmailAddress),
                active: (state) =>
                {
                    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.EmailAddress);
                })
                .Field(nameof(AdultOptionCount),
                validate: async (state, value) =>
                {
                    var result = new ValidateResult { Value = value };
                    result.IsValid = IsInteger(value);
                    return result;
                })
                .Field(nameof(ChildOptionCount),
                validate: async (state, value) =>
                {
                    var result = new ValidateResult { Value = value };
                    result.IsValid = IsInteger(value);
                    return result;
                })
                .Build();

        return (IForm<ApplyForm>)form;
    }

    private async Task AfterBuildForm(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<ApplyForm> result)
    {
        context.Done(result);
    }

    private static bool IsInteger(object value)
    {
        try
        {
            var s = value.ToString();
            int n;
            if (int.TryParse(s, out n))
                return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I tested your code, only I used a fake email address and replace your `CustomForm.CreateCustomForm` method with `new FormBuilder` for test purpose, but I can't reproduce your problem, when I input "reset", it will go through "StartAsync" method by my side. My bot version is 3.12.2.4. Could you please provide more detail so can I try to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I get the same result

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, I have been working on the same code for a few hours trying to figure things out so it has changed a bit. I updated the main text and code - I did test that same code several times and I get the same issue (Firstname now instead of emailAddress for some reason). I have the same bot version 3.12.2.4 - changing from `CreateCustomForm` to `new FormBuilder` didn't change the result but commenting out some Fields did (see update).

Comment: @Oyen, sorry I still cannot reproduce your issue, strange problem. Could you please share me your code about how you call this dialog?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I call it `context.Call(new ApplyForm(), CallReceiveDialog)` like that. I updated the text above with more details... Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: @Oyen, sorry, no idea, your issue still cannot reproduced on my side. If it is possible, would do you mind to upload a minimal reproduce-able demo?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT sure! I have never done that... Is there instructions on how I upload that here in stackoverflow? Or do I just upload it on my personal account and make it publicly available for download? I will make a separate project and upload it... Do I have to include my actual subscriptionkeys or do I just leave those blank?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Hi! I updated the main question again and included a full working code that you can just plug into RootDialog.cs to test. I also updated the conversation snippet to reflect the actual included code.

Comment: @Oyen, you can upload it to your github without any id or key like personal stuff, make a simplist reproducable demo would be great. Thx.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT here it is: https://github.com/oyen/OyenSolution

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your demo, I reproduced your issue finally and understand the question is that after `reset`, if there is `active` condition on the first field, it will ignore it and still prompt for the first field.

The `StartAsync` method is called actually again when input `reset`, so you default value is successfully set. This can be proved by checking the result after completing the whole flow, even the first field is been asked again and user input another value for this field, it will remain to submit the pre-set value which is got in `StartAsync` as the final result.

So to avoid the issue, I can only suggest not to prompt a field which is conditional active for the first field of `FormFlow` for now, means there're many workarounds to solve this problem but the solution based on this idea appears to be not graceful.

For example, here is one workaround: using different `FormFlow` based on the pre-set `CustomerAccount`:

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    var state = new ApplyForm();

    CustomerAccount customerAccount;
    FormDialog<ApplyForm> form;
    if (context.UserData.TryGetValue<CustomerAccount>("CustomerAccount", out customerAccount))
    {
        state.FirstName = customerAccount.FirstName;
        state.EmailAddress = customerAccount.Email;

        form = new FormDialog<ApplyForm>(
            state,
            BuildForm2,
            FormOptions.PromptInStart);
    }
    else
    {
        form = new FormDialog<ApplyForm>(
              state,
              BuildForm1,
              FormOptions.PromptInStart);
    }
    context.Call(form, this.AfterBuildForm);
}

[Prompt("What is your **{&}**?")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Prompt("What is your **{&}**?")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

[Numeric(0, 15)]
[Prompt("How many adults will attend?")]
public int AdultOptionCount { get; set; }

[Numeric(0, 15)]
[Prompt("How many children will attend?")]
public int ChildOptionCount { get; set; }

public static IForm<ApplyForm> BuildForm1()
{
    var form = new FormBuilder<ApplyForm>()
        .Field(nameof(FirstName))
        .Field(nameof(EmailAddress))
        .Field(nameof(AdultOptionCount),
            validate: async (state, value) =>
            {
                var result = new ValidateResult { Value = value };
                result.IsValid = IsInteger(value);
                return result;
            })
            .Field(nameof(ChildOptionCount),
            validate: async (state, value) =>
            {
                var result = new ValidateResult { Value = value };
                result.IsValid = IsInteger(value);
                return result;
            })
            .Build();

    return (IForm<ApplyForm>)form;
}

public static IForm<ApplyForm> BuildForm2()
{
    var form = new FormBuilder<ApplyForm>()
            .Field(nameof(AdultOptionCount),
            validate: async (state, value) =>
            {
                var result = new ValidateResult { Value = value };
                result.IsValid = IsInteger(value);
                return result;
            })
            .Field(nameof(ChildOptionCount),
            validate: async (state, value) =>
            {
                var result = new ValidateResult { Value = value };
                result.IsValid = IsInteger(value);
                return result;
            })
            .Build();

    return (IForm<ApplyForm>)form;
}

//other code goes here
```

This workaround is ungraceful cause it abandon the use of `active` condition for `Field` when building a `FormFlow`.

In the meantime, I've submitted this issue and I will update my answer if I get any new information. Thanks for sharing your demo.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think I can wait for an actual solution/update instead of applying a hack :) I am still poking around stuff for the bot and I'm happy with the responsiveness of the team :) Thanks again!